# Applescript Tell Application launched by specific user

Tags: applescript

I am running two Skype on the same computer: one is launched normally and the other one is launched in Terminal under a different user account B.

Then, I want to use Applescript to Tell application "Skype" (which is launched by account B) to do something. How should I specific the instance of Skype that is launched by account B in Applescript?

Many thanks!

miu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out to solve it by creating two copies of Skype.app and rename the new one "Skype2.app". Skpye.app is launched by user A and Skype2.app by user B (via Terminal). Then, in Applescript

```
tell application "Skype"
 -- do something for user A
end tell

tell application "Skype2"
 -- do something else for user B
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this can be done without duplicating/renaming the app if you enable remote apple events on your mac. (This is a system preference under sharing, and requires admin clearance, although you can restrict which users are allowed to send apple events, which I would recommend for security reasons).

Once that is done, you should be able to do something like:

```
tell application "Skype" of machine "eppc://userB@127.0.0.1"
 -- whatever
end tell
```

`userB` is of course the user name of user B, and `127.0.0.1` means 'this machine' or more correctly 'local host'.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion using remote event but it didn't work. Applescript couldn't identify the right instance of Skype that is launched by userB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. However I have thought of a work-around. Here's the idea. You can target an application several ways, one of them by its bundle identifier. For example to target TextEdit you could do this...

```
tell application id "com.apple.TextEdit" to activate
```

With that in mind, your 2 running versions of skype would need to have different bundle ids so you can target them separately. That's not the case right now but you can make that happen. Just duplicate the skype application (make a copy). Then open the package contents of the copy, open the "info.plist" file in there, find the bundle identifier key, and change it to something else. Now you have 2 versions of skype with different bundle ids which means you can target them separately.

I checked this using TextEdit. I made a duplicate copy and set its bundle id to "com.apple.myTextEdit". I opened both applications and could target them separately. So user B could use "com.apple.myTextEdit" and the normal user would use "com.apple.TextEdit"... or vice versa.

It's not an ideal solution but it would work.